# Custom react-scripts for create react app doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

#### What do I want to achieve?

For project that im currently working on and projects in the future, I'm looking for a way to customise [create-react-app](/questions/tagged/create-react-app) to my needs. For example I would like to customise the webpack configuration.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. I've created a fork from the create-react-app repository. (version 3.4.1)
2. I've changed the webpack configuration and I have uploaded the custom [react-script](/questions/tagged/react-script) to [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enorm-react-scripts).
3. After that I used the following script to install cra with my custom script

   npx create-react-app test-app --scripts-version enorm-react-scripts --use-npm

#### The problem

For some reason when I use the script above the app installs perfectly fine. However it turns out that it doesn't use our customised webpack script / customised react-scripts package which is hosted on NPM. When I use the alias @components for example which is present in the customised webpack configuration, the app fails.

#### Environment & versions

```
"create-react-app": "^3.4.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1"
```

[My Github Customised Webpack in react-scripts](https://github.com/Tallock/create-react-app)